# I have problem installing gensim module. I installed numpy and scipy dependent modules successfully but was getting error while installing gensim

Tags: python

Here is error:

```
C:\Users\Dell>py -m pip install gensim
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
Collecting gensim
  Using cached gensim-4.1.2.tar.gz (23.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -etuptools (c:\users\dell\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages)
```